# Dealing with boss and his request to (male) employees including myself, how to handle this right?

Tags: management, legal, bullying, harassment, sexual-harassment

I work for a small firm here in Minnesota; only 30 people work there. Well, 27 men, 3 women. I[m a 37 year old guy, married, to my wife, 34, with a 14 year old daughter in highschool.

Our boss (a dude in his 50s) sent a circular email to all employees in the office (well, the guys only) asking them to send him selfies of themselves in their underwear, and that he wanted an "Underwear Friday" every week, where the guys walk around in their underwear (it applies *only* to the guys according to the email).

The email also asked the employees to take selfies of themselves sitting in their underwear on freeways as well (but isn't that illegal; well, sitting on the freeway part anyway?) and then post them on our firm's Twitter, Facebook and Instagram.

It also asked some of the guys to walk around the office in a bikini. I found this weird and it crept me out.

Our firm deals in graphic design etc. and we have important clients visiting and meetings etc.

I confronted the boss on Friday in private after work, told him that this was inappropriate, he said:

> I'm the boss. You're just gonna have to accept that you'll do what you don't want to at work. ven if it means being in just your pants. God, dude, feel the freedom of being in your pants. Every dude wants to do it, it's gonna be a hoooot!! Fuck it with your complaining, you don't stick it to the man here. Who do you think you are. George fucking Clooney? Give me a break. is your ego as big as your, you know what, your... aaaagh, yah know what I mean. Just show up in your pants next Friday from 9am or else you're not gonna be paid a cent. Got it? It's gonna be hot seeing employees in their pants.

BTW, the boss is married, met his wife and son once, they seemed like nice enough guys so why the hell is he doing this?

This is weird behavior. The boss is normally straight as an arrow and he now announces this?

He's got a reputation around the office as a "Mr. Tough Guy" and straight-talking, and this request is so left-field I don't know what the hell to do. I told him no, he refused to accept it.

I freelanced for 18 months before getting the job in March, before now there was no conflict, it was a good job, I've only been there nearly 4 months now.

Why would the boss do this? Is this something I could sue over? How should i deal with this?

BTW, aside from digital publishing, the boss has also asked me to do some email stuff for him (since I have IT and marketing skills), he occasionally asked me to check his email since he doesn't have time to respond to all of them. I noticed he'd sent an email to a certain female celebrity's management claiming one of the employees has cancer in order to get the celebrity to visit (the employee/my co-worker does **not** have cancer, he was in my local paper promoting some new community-related initiative a few months ago and was large as life. FFS, the co-worker is 21 and I know him from sports activities anyway!).
The employee is a fan of that celebrity, he's seen her in concert, but nothing more than that.

Why would my boss do this and what should I do next? Do I need a lawyer? (and hopefully not a Saul Goodman-type one; started watching that on Netflix) Or what next?

I like where I work, have no issues with co-workers, but the issue with the boss is causing me so much stress I feel like I could explode.

Dealing with this conflict is causing me stress and my wife and daughter are noticing it and I haven't told them why, other than "work stress", partially out of embarrassment.

Comment: What does your company do?

Comment: Personally, I'd drop a note to the boss's wife, stating the facts and saying you're a bit concerned that he may need his meds adjusted... this sounds like mania to me. Of course if the boss hears about that you may lose your job, but it sounds like unless he gets some help don't want to stay there anyway. (I say this as someone on the other end of that axis.)

Comment: I work in the graphic design industry; InDesign, Photoshop, Quark XPress etc.

Comment: No one at the job handles HR issues? Assuming you're in the US it sounds like the [law applies to this situation](https://www.eeoc.gov/laws/types/sexual_harassment.cfm).

Comment: I wonder if getting 27 lawsuits for sexual harrassment filed against you would be a record. Plus 3 women suing for discrimination :-)

Comment: Sounds like he has a brain tumour [this comment is 100% serious].

Comment: Does he has a boss that you can go to?  This sounds like a major HR violation.

Comment: If the reason you haven't told your wife is that you're embarrassed about the situation, please reconsider. It's the boss that should be embarrassed, not you.

Comment: `I found this weird and it crept me out.` - Dude, I don't work for your company and it creeps *me* out.

Comment: @TheMathemagician That was my first  thought upon reading it, also.  It should be high on your list of suspects when faced with major and uncharacteristic behavior changes.

Comment: There are a few passive aggressive ideas I can think of, such as wearing your underwear outside like Superman, but that is frowned upon, so I will just leave this as a comment.

Comment: OP, please forgive me, but as I was reading this I couldn't help but consider the idea that this may be a *troll post.* The scenario just sounds so ridiculous. Now, I'm not calling you a troll, as I have no way of knowing. But assuming this is a true story, then as others have said: Send an anonymous message to his wife informing her of his behavior. Start searching for a new job asap.

Comment: The email is part is ridiculous enough to look a joke, the "answer" of the boss unmasks it as a troll

Comment: Ah, The Wolf-Whistler of Warhol Street. :)

Comment: Well this is an entertaining read but it doesn't have an answerable core question. VTC.

Comment: -1 obvious troll is obvious

Comment: "No." is a complete sentence...

Comment: Not having to wear pants to the office? Sounds like you hit the jackpot (aside from the selfie part)

Comment: My suspicion here is either that this is a troll post or the boss' email was hacked

Answer (score 42):

"Just show up in your pants next Friday from 9am or else you're not gonna be paid a cent. Got it?"

Well, that's sexual harrassment, no doubt about that.

If you want to be nice, call his wife, tell her what is happening, and maybe she can get him under control. That would be the best possible outcome. The Mathemagician may be correct with his comment, that this could be a brain tumor or something similar that affects him mentally.

If not, well, I don't think you will be paid for long anyway, because the company will be gone soon. So start looking for a new job immediately. That has higher priority than any work for clients, for example.

There is no need to be stressing about this. There's nothing you can do about his antics, just ignore them. Accept that your job and the whole business may be gone soon because being mad is not good for any business, and take that as a base line. Should he do something stupid like not paying you, then it's time to get a lawyer, and as I said earlier, what he's doing *is* sexual harrassment with tons of witnesses.

PS. In the other case, that this is just an a**hole on a power trip, being obviously worried about his health and calling for psychiatric help would be deeply insulting to him, which would also be just exactly what you would want in that case.

Comment: Since I suspect the cause is medical I think talking to her should be the first thing.  If she doesn't fix it then it's time to eject.

Answer (score 36):

In situations like this, I just assume the person is on drugs and I move on. This is out of control behaviour, waste of time trying to work out why.

Brush up your CV and start job hunting before someone goes off the deep end.

Comment: Boss of a graphic design company acting manic, sure sounds like white lines to me.

Comment: "Move on, it's a waste of time trying to figure out why" takes being practical past the point of cynicism and laziness, in my opinion. As @TheMathemagician pointed out, this could easily be a brain tumor or the onset of some serious mental illness, especially if that person has never displayed this kind of behavior before. Reporting this to his wife specifically with the advice to get him medically checked out, is the right thing to do; not just packing your bags and moving on mercenary style.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff If a boss spoke to me like that he'd be close to losing his front teeth, better if I leave quietly. I couldn't care less about his mental health issues, I'm not his mum.

Comment: @Kilisi, This has nothing to do with being his mother. You would hope that we would strive to live in a society in which people give others the benefit of the doubt, whereby when someone starts acting completely out of character the first thing that comes to your mind isn't to choose between punching him in the face or abandoning ship, but instead to realize there might be something medically seriously wrong with him and at least try to get him some help. I'm not asking you to be his mother; letting his family know would already be a positive step.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff that's too deep for me, I'm at work for the money. I leave the philosophy for those who can afford it.

Comment: @Kilisi, I don't think you understand the definition of the word philosophy, and your point about being able to "afford it" makes no sense. Nothing is lost but a few minutes of your time and the upside is potentially huge (saving someone's life). I would think that someone working in your field would have at least a very basic understanding of the concept of expected value. The "value" in EV doesn't necessarily stand for money. But I guess I was right on the money (pun intended) about you when I said "moving on mercenary style".

Comment: Yep, sounds like you have me figured out :)

Comment: @jeremyradcliff The logical implication is that Kilisi is the only person who knows of the boss's erratic behavior and that family and friends are totally oblivious; or that Kilisi has a greater obligation than family and friends.

Comment: @emory. You're essentially saying "no need to do anything because others know about it too". That kind of thinking has historically proven to be catastrophical. Family and friends could know about this but also might not since according to the OP, his boss showed "normal" behavior before outside of work. But again, why take the risk? Yes, maybe someone else will do something, maybe his wife and friends already know about it? But what if they don't? Finally, your last point makes no sense whatsoever. I'm not making an argument for an "obligation" from a legal or even moral standpoint. (cont'd)

Comment: @emory (cont'd). I'm making an argument from a practical standpoint. Act to make your environment one in which you would like to live. Trying to prioritize who has a greater obligation than someone else and whether or not having a somehow lower obligation than another should let you walk away with a clean conscience is in my opinion completely pointless and counterproductive.
If you suffered from a mental condition, wouldn't you like someone to try to do something about it instead of debating whether to break your teeth or just walk away?

Comment: You don't take work issues to a persons family, that's just out of line, I have no idea why you think it's ok (or the other answers), and I'm not a doctor and nor is the OP. I'm not going to argue about it, because it makes no sense to me, and never will.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if it's worth trying to reason with someone this unreasonable but, if you do want to try talking to him again, don't do it alone in private. You and your co-workers should speak to him as a group to tell him that this is illegal and no one is going to walk around naked or send nude photos. He might back down when faced with the fact that he'd need to re-hire his entire staff* but you should be prepared for him to make good on his threat.

*This includes the women working there too. I can't imagine they want to see all of their male co-workers walking around nude either.

Since you mention lawyering up, I want to point out that:

> All of the laws enforced by [the U.S. Equal Employment Opportunity Commission], except for the Equal Pay Act, **require** you to file a Charge of Discrimination with us before you can file a job discrimination lawsuit against your employer. In addition,
>   an individual, organization, or agency may file a charge on behalf of
>   another person in order to protect the aggrieved person's identity.
>   **There are time limits for filing a charge.**

<sup>https://www.eeoc.gov/employees/charge.cfm</sup>

If you do want to follow through on this (rather than just getting the heck out of Dodge) look into local discrimination laws and see if there are any local organizations that can help you.